# Inserting the command line text before output in stdout (for pipe / redirection)

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout

Consider the following `bash` constructs:

```bash
ls /usr/include/asm > list-redir.txt
ls /usr/include/asm | tee list-tee.txt
```

In this case, `list-redir.txt` and `list-tee.txt` will be identical, and will contain the listing of files as expected; e.g.

```
$ head -5 list-redir.txt
a.out.h
auxvec.h
bitsperlong.h
boot.h
bootparam.h [...]
```

My question is - how could I write such a command, and have the command line text inserted as the first thing in the standard output - such that the file eventually starts with the command line as first? As an example, the file `list-redir.txt` would in that case look like:

```
$ head -5 list-redir.txt
# ls /usr/include/asm
a.out.h
auxvec.h
bitsperlong.h
boot.h [...]
```

... which also implies that the character # can be prepended to the inserted command line.

Is there anything that I could use for this - but with the minimum of change in typing out in respect to the original command lines (`ls /usr/include/asm > list-redir.txt` ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple (and ugly) hack would be to add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
echorun(){
    echo "# $@";
    "$@"
}
```

You'd then run your command as

```
echorun ls /usr > list-redir.txt
```

That will not let you differentiate between `ls /usr >foo` and `ls /usr | tee foo` but it will append `# ls /usr` to the beginning of `foo`.

Comment: Many thanks @terdon - I'll be accepting this, as it looks like it minimizes the amount of typing; I didn't need to differentiate between redirection and piping, so it looks good. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this:

```
{   cmd="ls /usr/include/asm"
    echo "$cmd" ; $cmd
} >./list-redir.txt
```

At least I think this is what you want done. This would yield results like:

```
 $ cat <./list-redir.txt

 ###OUTPUT###

   ls /usr/include/asm
 #output of above command#
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that @mikeserv - the other answer has also a note about a shorter usage on command line, so I accepted that one. Cheers!

Comment: Cool by me, @sddau - it's a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just realized that the answer from @terdon may not work with a more complicated command pipeline; so I came up with the following alias (named `er` as short for @tendon's `echorun`):

```
#alias er=' cat <(echo "# cmd: $(history 1)") - | tee' # last tee is not needed, so:
alias er=' cat <(echo "# cmd: $(history 1)") -'
```

The idea is, basically, that `|er` should be inserted before the last pipe or redirect in a command line; then, it is a lucky coincidence indeed, that at that point, `history 1` exactly refers to the current command line! Thus, it can be echoed first, before the rest of (what is at that point) standard input, by `cat`. And so, we can now do things like:

```
$ ls /usr/include/asm | grep 'p*.h' | grep 'osix' |er | tee mylist.txt
# cmd:   125  ls /usr/include/asm | grep 'p*.h' | grep 'osix' |er | tee mylist.txt
posix_types_32.h
posix_types_64.h
posix_types.h
$ ls /usr/include/asm | grep 's*.h' | grep 'ig' |er >> mylist.txt
$ cat mylist.txt 
# cmd:   125  ls /usr/include/asm | grep 'p*.h' | grep 'osix' |er | tee mylist.txt
posix_types_32.h
posix_types_64.h
posix_types.h
# cmd:   126  ls /usr/include/asm | grep 's*.h' | grep 'ig' |er >> mylist.txt
sigcontext32.h
sigcontext.h
siginfo.h
signal.h
```

Thus we have full command line of multiple pipes - and we don't have to worry about escaping anything - basically, just add `er` to the last pipe. The only slight nag is the history number (it doesn't bother me that much, otherwise I'd add an additional `awk` in the alias).

Comment: @sddau - you could probably do this portably like `alias er=' eval "$(fc -l 0)"'` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the `script` command which will record your terminal session including what you type and all the output.  It can get a little messy though sometimes as it will record everything you type including any backspaces etc.

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
$ ls /usr/include/asm
a.out.h          ioctl.h      mtrr.h             setup.h         termios.h
auxvec.h         ioctls.h     param.h            shmbuf.h        types.h
bitsperlong.h    ipcbuf.h     poll.h             sigcontext32.h  ucontext.h
boot.h           ist.h        posix_types_32.h   sigcontext.h    unistd_32.h
bootparam.h      kvm.h        posix_types_64.h   siginfo.h       unistd_64.h
byteorder.h      kvm_para.h   posix_types.h      signal.h        unistd.h
debugreg.h       ldt.h        prctl.h            socket.h        vm86.h
e820.h           mce.h        processor-flags.h  sockios.h       vsyscall.h
errno.h          mman.h       ptrace-abi.h       statfs.h
fcntl.h          msgbuf.h     ptrace.h           stat.h
hw_breakpoint.h  msr.h        resource.h         swab.h
hyperv.h         msr-index.h  sembuf.h           termbits.h
$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
$ cat typescript
Script started on Sat 29 Aug 2015 10:32:52 AM EDT
$ ls /usr/include/asm
a.out.h          ioctl.h      mtrr.h             setup.h         termios.h
auxvec.h         ioctls.h     param.h            shmbuf.h        types.h
bitsperlong.h    ipcbuf.h     poll.h             sigcontext32.h  ucontext.h
boot.h           ist.h        posix_types_32.h   sigcontext.h    unistd_32.h
bootparam.h      kvm.h        posix_types_64.h   siginfo.h       unistd_64.h
byteorder.h      kvm_para.h   posix_types.h      signal.h        unistd.h
debugreg.h       ldt.h        prctl.h            socket.h        vm86.h
e820.h           mce.h        processor-flags.h  sockios.h       vsyscall.h
errno.h          mman.h       ptrace-abi.h       statfs.h
fcntl.h          msgbuf.h     ptrace.h           stat.h
hw_breakpoint.h  msr.h        resource.h         swab.h
hyperv.h         msr-index.h  sembuf.h           termbits.h
$ exit
exit

Script done on Sat 29 Aug 2015 10:33:00 AM EDT
```